# Create a WebPart which displays people who have rights on lists

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, web-parts, designer

I want to develop a WebPart in C# to display peoples who have a certain right on the list of the SharePoint page.
So I began by creating a "Visual Web Part" in VS2010, and in the View Designer I add a DataList because I think it is the most relevant.
But now, I don't know how to link my data with this DataList.
It ask me for an XML file but which one choose ? And where can I take it ?
After all, how to make this WebPart generic with all my SharePoint pages which implements one list ?

Comment: Have you developed any Web Parts before? :)

Comment: No any ! I'm a beginner and it's for a course...

Answer (score 0):

Why not audience target the web part to a SharePoint or AD group? Or build a view to show only items assigned to individuals?